# WCF Active STS (WS-Trust) : Access is denied at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AuthorizationBehavior.Authorize for JAVA clients

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, ws-trust

I am creating an Active STS that authenticates RST using issued tokens (SAML1, SAML2) and issues BinarySecurityTokens.
This is working fine for .net clients. However, **RST from Java clients** (code, SOAP UI etc), we **get following exception**-

```
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.FaultException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Access is denied.</Message>
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.AuthorizationBehavior.Authorize(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
       at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)...
```

I suspect the issue is with serviceAuthorization for the binding. However, I could not find any documentation on configuring authorization for Claims Based authentication. Here is my configuration -
behavior-

```
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior name="">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
</behavior>
<behavior name="WSTrustServiceBehaviour">
  <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" identityConfiguration="STSIDConfig">
    <issuedTokenAuthentication audienceUriMode="Never" certificateValidationMode="None">
    </issuedTokenAuthentication>
  </serviceCredentials>
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
  <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
  <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

binding

```
<ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
<clear/>
<binding name="WS2007FedttpBinding">
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <message establishSecurityContext="false" issuedKeyType="BearerKey">
    </message>
  </security>
</binding>
</ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
```

Service-

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WSTrustServiceBehaviour" name="CustomSTS">
    <endpoint name="WSTrust13HttpEndpoint" address="" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS2007FedttpBinding" contract="System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrust13SyncContract" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

Pls let me know what is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that ws2007FederationHttpBinding requires RST to have WS-Addressing headers and the access denied error was occuring due to WS-Addressing headers were missing for requests coming from java clients. 
I didn't find an option to disable WS-Addressing for ws2007FederationHttpBinding so for now we have requested clients to add WS-Addressing headers.